# Cannot scroll on React page after the modal popup closes. Content also disappears if I simply refersh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const PartnerCardSingular = (props) => {
  //console.log(props);
  // all the cards below are sample cards

  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [amt, setAmt] = useState(0);
  const [cc, setCc] = useState("");
  const [e, setE] = useState("");
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(0);
  let claim_submit_id = "claim_submit-" + props.name + "_button";
  let claim_rewards_id = "claim_rewards-" + props.title + "_button";

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
    Axios.get(bh + "/getUser")
      .then((response) => {
        const user = localStorage.getItem("email");
        const result = response.data;
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          if (result[i].email === user) {
            setPoints(result[i].points);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  const myRef = useRef(null);
  
  const handleOk = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const onFinish = async (values) => {
    let date = new Date();
    let today = `${date.getDate()}/${
      date.getMonth() + 1
    }/${date.getFullYear()}`;
    let fullname = localStorage.getItem("user");
    let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    let partnercode = "DBS";
    let memid = values.membership_number;
    let amt = values.amount;
    let lpro = props.card.title;
    await Axios.post(bh + "/createtransaction", {
      memberid: memid,
      fullname: fullname,
      amount: amt,
      date: today,
      partnercode: partnercode,
      loyaltyprogramme: lpro,
      email: email,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setCc(response.data.referenceNumber);
        handleOk();
        setSuccess(true);
        setAmt(amt);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response.status == 403) {
          alert("Insufficient points");
        }
        console.warn(err);
      });
    sendOnSubmit(values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };
```

There's some more code, omitted for irrelevance...

```
  return (
    <div className="card" onLoad={executeScroll}>
      <div className="card__body">
        <div style={{ display: loading ? "block" : "none" }}>
          <Spin />
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: loading ? "none" : "block" }}>
          <img
            src={props.card.img}
            className="card__image"
            alt="company logo"
            onLoad={imageLoaded}
          />
        </div>
        <h2 className="card__title">{props.card.programName}</h2>
        <p className="card__description">{props.card.description} </p>
      </div>
      <button
        id={"claim_rewards_" + props.card.programName}
        type="primary"
        onClick={showModal}
        className="card__btn hover hover__btn"
      >
        Claim rewards
      </button>

      <Modal
        title={props.card.title}
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        footer={null}
      >
        <Form
          name="basic"
          labelCol={{
            span: 8,
          }}
          wrapperCol={{
            span: 16,
          }}
          onFinish={onFinish}
          onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
          autoComplete="off"
        >
          <Form.Item
            label="Membership number"
            name="membership_number"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input membership ID",
              },
              {
                pattern: new RegExp(
                  /^(\d{9}|\d{10}|\d{12}|\d{16}|[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{1})$/
                ),
                message: "Please input valid membership ID",
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            label="Amount (Min is 1)"
            name="amount"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input amount of points to transfer",
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input
              type="number"
              name="test_name"
              min="1"
              oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"
            />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
            wrapperCol={{
              offset: 8,
              span: 16,
            }}
          >
            <Button
              id={"claim_submit_" + props.card.programName}
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
export default PartnerCardSingular;
```

So the code given aboverenders a page that looks like this:
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5QqT.png)

When I click on claim rewards, it gives me a modal that looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krEiX.png)

After clicking submit on the modal popup, everything on the under tha navbar disappears . Not sure why? Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you breaking your code into smaller components that will help you find the bug. The code what you have shared is too long. Not to many people willing to read it and think about your problem.

Comment: @BotondBalogh Thanks for getting back. I think the whole code is relavant to the problem as I suspect one of the following things:
1. Once an Axios. request is made, the re-render does not take place.
2. The re-render does not take place because of Modal is placed at the end of the code